# JAVA_HOME is not valid when trying to start NIFI

Tags: java, apache-nifi

Running on a mac. Just downloaded JAVA 1.8.0_311 in order to run nifi 1.14.0.  I am following instructions from a book  that instructs me to set the environment variable like so.

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java11-openjdk-amd64` when I do this I get a nifi message saying the path is invalid. The book is a year old so the examples may be a little outdated. I am trying to teach myself so I have some basic questions, and nifi documentation doesn't seem to have any input for JAVA_HOME.

How do I determine what the JAVA_HOME variable is supposed to be? I have seen others mention that the variable needs to point to `bin` or `jdk` but I'm not grasping why or how.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The example provides a path to Java 11 while you said you had dowloaded Java 8. Try editing the path to JDK and see if it helps your problem.

Comment: I am still trying to get a hang of understanding paths. what part of ```/usr/lib/jvm/java11-openjdk-amd64``` needs to be replaced with ```jdk```

Comment: JDK stands for Java Development Kit, it's basically what should have downloaded. Once you have installed it, provide a path to it under JAVA_HOME variable, so nifi could understand where to look for Java you have downloaded.

Comment: The absolute easiest way to do this is to use SDK MAN - https://sdkman.io/install - then `sdk install java 1.8.0-open` - then and select yes when it asks if you want to use it as the default. It will handle installing & setting ENV VARS for you. https://sdkman.io/usage. I use this for running local NiFI instances when I'm testing.

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly with "Data Engineering with Python. Work with massive datasets to design data models and automate data pipelines using Python" from Packt Publishing (2020):

you should edit .bash_profile to include the following line so that NiFi
can find the JAVA_HOME variable:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java11-openjdk-amd64
```

7. Lastly, reload .bash_profile:

source .bash_profile

Open a terminal, type:

```
dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which javac)))
```

Copy the path, then open another terminal and type (using nano editor):

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Then paste the path next to JAVA_HOME variable:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java11-openjdk-amd64
```

Ctrl-O, Enter, Ctrl-X, to exit nano editor.

Last, type, in the last terminal:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Reboot system

Answer (score 0):

From the comments I was able to piece together the following path and saved it in `/.bash_profile`:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score 0):

You have probably solved this by now but if you are still having trouble that is because there's a typo in your Java path it should be

/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64   NOT

/usr/lib/jvm/java11-openjdk-amd64

You can also confirm this by first going to the path. You may also need to add "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java11-openjdk-amd64" to nifi-env.sh.